# org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBMarshalException: A valid XmlRegistry could

Tags: java, jaxb, jetty, provider

While migrating rest-easy jaxrs 2.1.0 GA jar to 3.0.12.final jar  by using jetty 6.1.11 getting exception like:

> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBMarshalException: A valid XmlRegistry could not find

Comment: Jetty 6 is EOL (End of Life) as of late 2009, consider upgrading to something stable and supported.

Comment: after updating also not working, please provide any alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with complex objects, annotate your main object with

`@XmlRootElement(name = "Document")`

For e.g: If you are getting this exception when you hit a resource, annotate the body object of that API with XmlRootElement.

```
....
@XmlRootElement(name = "Document")
public class Person {
   @XmlElement(name = "Id")
   private int id;
   @XmlElement(name = "Name")
   private String name;
....
}
```